# How do I test existence of two mounts in cron before proceeding with rsync?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, rsync, cron

I have two mounts, in ubuntu, (one of which is a finicky windows share I'm backing up), and to prevent messes, I'd like to check mount existence of both, before the next step.  I tried:

`if   grep -qs '/media/namespace ' /proc/mounts && grep -qs '/media/Data/Y-1Current ' /proc/mounts ; then rsync -av --delete /media/namespace/ /media/Data/Y-1Current/; fi`

Is there a syntax, or more fundamental error preventing the line from executing the then portion?

Answer (score 0):

My mount check was on a sub-folder of the mount, not the mount itself.
It runs as expected with that correction.